# installing java on freeBSD

Tags: java, freebsd

I have a FreeBSD server with root access and I'm trying to install java on it.
I've tried to install diablo from the /usr/ports/java/diablo-jre15 directory, and it gave me a URL to download a file to /usr/ports/distfiles/. I did what it said, and then I ran:

```
make install clean
```

and it gave me the following error:

```
===>  Vulnerability check disabled, database not found
===>  Found saved configuration for diablo-jre-1.5.0.07.01_9
===>  Extracting for diablo-jre-1.5.0.07.01_9
=> MD5 Checksum mismatch for diablo-latte-freebsd6-i386-1.5.0_07-b01.tar.bz2.
=> SHA256 Checksum mismatch for diablo-latte-freebsd6-i386-1.5.0_07-b01.tar.bz2.
===>  Refetch for 1 more times files: diablo-latte-freebsd6-i386-1.5.0_07-b01.tar.bz2 diablo-latte-freebsd6-i386-1.5.0_07-b01.tar.bz2
===>  Vulnerability check disabled, database not found
===>  Found saved configuration for diablo-jre-1.5.0.07.01_9
=> diablo-latte-freebsd6-i386-1.5.0_07-b01.tar.bz2 doesn't seem to exist in /usr/ports/distfiles/.
=> Attempting to fetch from ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/.
fetch: transfer timed out
=> Couldn't fetch it - please try to retrieve this
=> port manually into /usr/ports/distfiles/ and try again.
*** Error code 1
```

I can see that the file is in the right directory and still it gives me the same error.

I'm using FreeBSD 6.2-RELEASE-p12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diablo JDK/DRE is horribly outdated. Don't use it.

Install `java/openjdk6` instead (or `java/openjdk7` if you want the devel version)

If these do not appear in your ports tree (as you're using a similarly horribly outdated, unsupported version of FreeBSD with known security vulnerabilities) you'll need to update it with [cvsup](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/cvsup.html), csup, or [portsnap](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/portsnap.html) (not sure if it that was available in 6.2).

Comment: ok, i've run the make install clean in the /usr/ports/cvsup..
what's next ?

Comment: i had an error in the cvsup installation.. can i download an installation of openjdk6 ?

Comment: If you're installing cvsup for the command line you'll want `usr/ports/net/cvsup-without-gui`; you can grab a package of the oJDK6 for the 6-Stable branch from ftp://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/ports/i386/packages-6-stable/java/openjdk6-b20_5.tbz <-- Note that's in the archives now... You can't automatically install packages with the `pkg_add -r $PKG_NAME` command anymore. Is upgrading to a newer version of FreeBSD an option at all?

Comment: nope, not for now.. this is a shared server...

Comment: i've used wget to download it, what now ? sorry its the first time i'm using freebsd (or linux) and i only know basic commands..

Comment: i've tried pck_add openjdk6-b20_5.tbz and it gave me:


pkg_add: could not find package xbitmaps-1.1.0 !
pkg_add: could not find package expat-2.0.1_1 !
pkg_add: could not find package javavmwrapper-2.3.5 !
pkg_add: could not find package pkg-config-0.25_1 !
pkg_add: could not find package fontconfig-2.8.0,1 !
pkg_add: could not find package dejavu-2.32 !
pkg_add: could not find package libpthread-stubs-0.3_3 !
pkg_add: could not find package libxcb-1.7 !
pkg_add: could not find package open-motif-2.2.3_6 !

Comment: Try doing a `setenv PACKAGESITE ftp://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/ports/i386/packages-6-stable/All/` then `pkg_add -r openjdk6-b20_5`.

Comment: ok done, it gave me lots of warnings about some packages i have which are not up to date, but it looks like it worked, but when i'm typing java it says java: Command not found.
thanks for your kind help, but what's next ? :)

Comment: Log out and back in again. Or run `/usr/local/bin/java`

Comment: all works, your are definitely my hero !